# Connection between Abel–Ruffini theorem and characteristic polynomial of matrices

Tags: matrices, roots

Suppose $n \times n$ matrix $M$ with arbitrary coefficient in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

In the general case, the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is a polynomial whose highest degree is $n$.

Is there a link between $n>4$ and the Abel–Ruffini theorem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Are the roots of a general $5 \times 5$ matrix subject to the Abel–Ruffini theorem limitations?

What requirements on $M$ must there be for its roots to be subject to the Abel–Ruffini theorem? Is it sufficient that the entries of $M$ be arbitrary?

Comment: A polynomial is soluble by radicals iff its Galois group is soluble. Lots is known about computing Galois groups of quintics, e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80574/galois-groups-at-closed-points-from-galois-group-at-generic-point  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38896/calculating-the-galois-group-of-an-irreducible-quintic I think the generic (in a suitable sense) Galois group is $\mathfrak{S}_5$, i.e. is not soluble.

Comment: Some trivial remarks: You should probably work over $\mathbf{Q}$ because over $\mathbf{C}$ all polynomials split so their Galois groups are trivial. All polynomials are realisable as the characteristic polynomials of some matrix, via companion matrices. A reasonable question might be what relations there are between the Galois group and other properties of the matrix, e.g. facts about its minors.

Comment: To the OP.  On this website, usage is, if one is satisfied with an answer, then one upvotes it  and (or) one gives the green ticket or, if one is not satisfied, then one writes why.

Comment: Thanks for the green ticket; that says that you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is random, then roughky speaking, its characteristic polynomial is random. Then we may consider a (non monic) random polynomial $p=\sum_{0\leq i\leq 5}a_ix^i\in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

The simplest method is to consider a positive integer $n$ and to randomly choose (independently) the $(a_i)$ uniformly in $\{-n..n\}$. Let $P_n$ be the associated probability that $p$ is irreducible and has $S_5$ as Galois group.

EDIT. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}P_n=1$. About this result, you can read

[1] J.P. Serre: Topics in Galois Theory.(the reading is hard)

[2] Igor Irvine: Galois groups of generic polynomials.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06446.pdf

A difficult problem is to estimate the speed of convergence towards $1$ of $P_n$; an upper bound is given in [1] and more precisely in [2].

To give an idea, here are the results of some random tests

$P_1\approx 28$%,$P_{10}\approx 85$%$,P_{100}\approx 98.2$%,$P_{1000}\approx 99.79$%.

Of course, $P_n$ depends on the degree of the polynomial $p$. When the degree increases, $P_n$ increases too.

Comment: Can you explain the need to limit the argument to the rationals. Everything I can find about the Abel–Ruffini theorem seems to suggest it applies to the reals. So I do not know why you need this limitation?